# Active apostrophe character in math mode

Tags: math-mode, active-characters

For some reason, I need a package providing an active apostrophe. For the sake of simplicity, let's say that every apostrophe shall be replaced by `ABC` in text mode. In math mode, the default behaviour shall remain.

The apostrophe character is defined as “math-active” in `latex.ltx`, lines 4548 to 4563:

```
\def\active@math@prime{^\bgroup\prim@s}
{\catcode`\'=\active \global\let'\active@math@prime}
\def\prim@s{%
  \prime\futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s}
\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}
\def\pr@@@s#1{\prim@s}
\def\pr@@@t#1#2{#2\egroup}
```

This code makes sure that a sequence of apostrophe characters is converted into a sequence of prime symbols in math mode.

To fulfil my needs, I have devised the following code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mypackage.sty}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ProvidesExplPackage {mypackage} {2019-09-20} {1.0} {My package}
\cs_new:Npn \mypackage_apostrophe:
  {
    \mode_if_math:TF
      {
        \active@math@prime % latex.ltx, line 4548
      }
      {
        ABC % dummy text for testing
      }
  }
\char_set_active_eq:NN ' \mypackage_apostrophe:
\NewDocumentCommand \Activate { }
  {
    \char_set_catcode_active:N '
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \Deactivate { }
  {
    \char_set_catcode_other:N '
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}
a'b $f'(x)$ $f''(x)$

\Activate
a'b $f'(x)$ $f''(x)$

\Deactivate
a'b $f'(x)$ $f''(x)$
\end{document}
```

This code produces an error message if the apostrophe character is active and a second derivation `$f''(x)$` is needed:

```
! Double superscript. \active@math@prime ->^
                      \bgroup \prim@s
l.30 a'b $f'(x)$ $f''
                   (x)$
```

How can I avoid this error message (keeping `'` as active)?

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
\catcode`\'=\active 
\def\svprime{\active@math@prime}
\def'{\ifmmode\expandafter\svprime\else\expandafter\ABC\fi}
\def\ABC{ABC}
```

almost had it working.  But then I *finally* realized that since `\pr@m@s` employs a test for the repeated `'`, I had to make `'` active before defining `\pr@m@s`, or else it would always fail the `\ifx` test for the repeated `'`.

Commented out are other parts associated with the `\prime` definition in `latex.ltx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\'=\active 
%\def\active@math@prime{^\bgroup\prim@s}
%{\catcode`\'=\active \global\let'\active@math@prime}
%\def\prim@s{%
%  \prime\futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s}
\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}
%\def\pr@@@s#1{\prim@s}
%\def\pr@@@t#1#2{#2\egroup}
\def'{\ifmmode\expandafter\active@math@prime\else\expandafter\ABC\fi}
\def\ABC{ABC}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Text mode: x'x
\begin{equation}
a = v'(t) = x''(t)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At which point of my above package code shall I insert `\def\pr@m@s{...}`? I cannot get it work.

Comment: @wehro I do not speak the syntax of expl3, so I can't provide a fix, but I would say, as part of *both* `\Activate` and `\Deactivate`, I would, after, redefining the catcode, issue the definition for `\pr@m@s`.

Comment: That sounds logical, but unfortunately, it does not work. The error message remains.

Answer (score 0):

The macro `\pr@m@s` still looks for a category code 12 apostrophe. Patching it is easy.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{'}{\cA'}{}{} % \pr@m@s should look for an active '
% now define the active '
\catcode`'=\active
\protected\def'{\ifmmode\expandafter\active@math@prime\else ABC\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

' in text mode

$f'+f''$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a real world it would probably be

```latex
\protected\def'{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\active@math@prime
  \else
    \expandafter\wehro@active@text@prime
  \fi
}
```

where `\wehro@active@text@prime` is the macro you want to use in text mode.

Comment: At which point of my above package code shall I insert `\regexpatchcmd...`? I cannot get it work.